# how to handle icon on click with semantic UI

Tags: semantic-ui

I am using semantic UI to create a basic front end and I am adding an icon as follows:

```
<div class="ui one column grid">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="ui basic segment center aligned">
                <i class="link home big icon"></i>
                
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now what I want to do is be able to call a function when the user clicks the icon in the segment. I tried to do something by simply adding:

```
<script>
     alert("Clicked");
</script>
```

assuming this would connect with the basic click handler but this does not seem to get invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function and add onClick even handler to trigger the function,

```
function handleClick(){
    alert("Clicked");
};
```

assuming you want to click

```
<i class="link home big icon"></i>
```

you can do

```
<i class="link home big icon" onClick="handleClick()"></i>
```